# Getting import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin can't be resolved error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting the error "import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin can't be resolved" in my code. Not able to compile the application. Here is the part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Both the Spring-web and spring-webmvc jars are there in the build path of the project. I'm new to spring and spring boot. It will be very much appreciated if somebody can help me here.

Comment: if you are using spring boot, just add this; <dependency<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId></dependency>

Comment: @Habil That is already there. Still I'm getting the compilation error.

Comment: That has been added in Spring 4.2, so trying to use it with Spring 4.1 will certainly will not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! It worked after I replaced the Spring 4 jars with Spring 5.